# Redirect to another page in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to redirect to another page `admin_antenna_reader_rfids_path` at the end of the `create` method. I did:

```
def create
    @antenna_reader_rfid = AntennaReaderRfid.new(antenna_reader_rfid_params)
      if @antenna_reader_rfid.save
        render json: {status: true}
        redirect_to admin_antenna_reader_rfid_path(q@antenna_reader_rfid)
      else
        render json: {errors: @antenna_reader_rfid.errors.full_messages, status: false}
    end
  end
```

I get an error `AbstractController :: DoubleRenderError`:

> Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle multiple request format, you can use [respond_to](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html#method-i-respond_to)

```
if @antenna_reader_rfid.save
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: { status: true } }
    format.html { redirect_to where_you_want_path }
  end
else
  # same way as above
end
```

Within the `respond_to` block, you can render all the request formats as you want, then based on the request header, the controller will choose the corresponding logic to respond to you.

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove the line `render json: {status: true}` as currently you're trying to make your controller render a json and redirect to an HTML page at the same time. You have to pick one.

Comment: That's bad, is there any way I can do these two form?

Comment: Can your controller be called through standard HTML submit and some other request, e.g. AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

You can't render nor return more than once in a method.